# Weird output from batch script

Tags: batch-file

I'm trying to log the output of the tree command from many remote PCs.

Here's my script

```
set myFile=multiPsexecList.txt

pushd %~dp0

mkdir RESULTS

for /F "tokens=*" %%i in (%myFile%) do (call :process %%i)
popd
goto :EOF

:process
 set thecomputer=%1
 echo %thecomputer%
 ping -n 1 %thecomputer% | find "TTL=" >nul 
 if errorlevel 1 ( 
     echo offline > RESULTS\OFFLINE_%thecomputer%.log
 ) else (
     net use t: \\%thecomputer%\c$
     tree t:\directory > RESULTS\%thecomputer%.log
     net use t: /delete
 )
```

The problem is that i get a weird output, as you can see below:

```
³   ÃÄÄÄDbTransactions
³   ³   ÃÄÄÄ2018-08-07
³   ³   ÃÄÄÄ2018-08-08
³   ³   ÃÄÄÄ2018-08-09
³   ³   ÃÄÄÄ2018-08-10
³   ³   ÃÄÄÄ2018-08-11
³   ³   ÃÄÄÄ2018-08-16
³   ³   ÃÄÄÄ2018-08-17
³   ³   ÃÄÄÄ2018-08-18
³   ³   ÃÄÄÄ2018-08-21
³   ³   ÃÄÄÄ2018-08-22
³   ³   ÃÄÄÄ2018-08-23
³   ³   ÃÄÄÄ2018-08-24
³   ³   ÃÄÄÄ2018-08-25
³   ³   ÃÄÄÄ2018-08-28
³   ³   ÃÄÄÄ2018-08-29
```

Which is partially correct, except for these "ÃÄÄÄ".

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Try `/a` argument with `tree` so that it uses ASCII instead of extended characters. View `tree /?` for help.

Comment: [Command Prompt "tree" shows Unicode in console but outputs to file in ASCII](https://superuser.com/q/1056614/241386)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The output is absolutely correct because it is:

```
│   ├───DbTransactions
│   │   ├───2018-08-07
│   │   ├───2018-08-08
│   │   ├───2018-08-09
│   │   ├───2018-08-10
│   │   ├───2018-08-11
│   │   ├───2018-08-16
│   │   ├───2018-08-17
│   │   ├───2018-08-18
│   │   ├───2018-08-21
│   │   ├───2018-08-22
│   │   ├───2018-08-23
│   │   ├───2018-08-24
│   │   ├───2018-08-25
│   │   ├───2018-08-28
│   │   ├───2018-08-29
```

What you don't know is how [characters are encoded](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_encoding) which every programmer should really know.

In console environment the character encoding is usually an **OEM** character encoding which means there is one byte used per character. So the number of characters is limited to `2^8 = 256` characters.

Open a command prompt window and run the command `chcp`. This command outputs the **code page** being set by default for console applications depending on the country configured for the used user account in Windows **Region and Language** settings. For example the code page [OEM 850](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_850) is used by default in Western European countries and similar code page [OEM 437](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_437) in North American countries.

But the code page used in GUI applications like Windows Notepad for text files with a character encoding using just one byte per character depending also on country setting is for example [Windows-1252](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252) in North American and Western European countries.

Look on the character sets of the referenced code pages:

- Byte with decimal value **179** is character `³` in Windows-1252 and character `│` in OEM 437/850.
- Byte with decimal value **195** is character `Ã` in Windows-1252 and character `├` in OEM 437/850.
- Byte with decimal value **196** is character `Ä` in Windows-1252 and character `─` in OEM 437/850.

So the output is not weird. You just view the text file with using a different code page as used for creating the text file.

The command `chcp` can be used in a console window with an argument to **ch**ange **c**ode **p**age. But the usage of `chcp 1252` at top of the batch file before running `tree t:\directory > RESULTS\%thecomputer%.log` is of no help because Windows-1252 has no box-drawing characters in its character set. That is the reason why command `tree` has the parameter `/A` as output in help on running `tree /?` to use [ASCII](http://www.asciitable.com/) characters instead of characters from extended character set of active code page.